# Last 7 days javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a report create time as 2016-05-30, now I need to get the last 7 days from the report time.How can I get using moment?

```
report_create_time = moment('2016-05-30').format('MMM DD, YYYY');
```

I see this but it gives 7 days from the current date but I want from the report_Create_time.

```
dateFrom = moment().subtract(7,'d').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Comment: `moment()` instead of `moment('2016-05-30')` ... you are specifying the current date

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking. Please add some clarification to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Small change needed

```
report_create_time = moment('2016-05-30');
dateFrom = report_create_time.subtract(7,'days');
report_create_time = report_create_time.format('MMM DD, YYYY'); // if you needed this formatted date to show in your HTML
```

`dateFrom` is the day before 7 days. so we need days from `dateFrom` to `report_create_time`

If you have both the dates, you can add 1 day from `dateFrom` up to seven days

```
var dates = []
for(var i=1; i<=7; i++){
    dates[i-1] = dateFrom.add('1', 'days').fotmat('MMM DD, YYYY')
}
```

If you don't need this way, you can **subtract 1 day from report_create_time 7 times**

Answer (score 0):

you can try this `pure javascript`

```
var d = new Date('2016-05-30');
var day = d.getDate() - 7;
var month = d.getMonth();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var d1 = new Date(year+"-"+month+"-"+day);
alert(d1);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c6c2vur8/

Comment: what if `day` is less than 7?